# How do I debug this error unknown class in Interface Builder FIle

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

Unknown class BGTableViewWithBackgroundAndTopBottom in Interface Builder file.

The problem is I have so many interface Builder class I do not know which one contains BGTableViewWithBackgroundAndTopBottom

Comment: Check when the error message is printing. I mean as a result of which nib file load

Comment: Any better way? XIB is a text file right?

Comment: yes xib is a text file, another way is search the error clas in the folder your project is located. Then see finder is filterin any xib file. Then open it as source code in xcode check if the class is in it (with find - cmd + F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open terminal and change the directory to the root of your project.  Then run:

```
grep -rnI "BGTableViewWithBackgroundAndTopBottom" .
```

This should display the filename and line number of the files containing the string "BGTableViewWithBackgroundAndTopBottom"

The options used for grep are:

- -r recursive
- -n show line numbers
- -I skip binary files